# Using integer value to get SQLite database table row data of row index in order to display said data in textviews in new activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to display my FLIGHTS table row data depending on the index in a activity using textviews. How do I get the index of the table row and display the table rows columns in textviews in an activity.

Here is my activity where I am trying to display the data in textviews:

```
package com.example.shashank.fffffffffffffffffffffffffff;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BookingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);



        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(intValue));


    }


}
```

the intValue variable I am getting from another activity which represents the position being clicked on a listview.
I am then trying to use that variable to display the row index of the FLIGHTS table into textviews.

Here is my DBHelper class:

```
package com.example.shashank.fffffffffffffffffffffffffff;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "Login.db";
    public static final String FLIGHTS = "FLIGHTS";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESTINATION = "DESTINATION";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRICE = "PRICE";
    public static final String COLUMN_DEPARTURE_TIME = "DEPARTURE_TIME";
    public static final String COLUMN_ARRIVAL_TIME = "ARRIVAL_TIME";
    public static final String COLUMN_DURATION = "DURATION";
    public static final String COLUMN_AVAILABLE_SEATS = "AVAILABLE_SEATS";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Login.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase MyDB) {

        String createTable1 = "create Table users(username TEXT primary key, password TEXT)";
        MyDB.execSQL(createTable1);

        MyDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + FLIGHTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_DESTINATION + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PRICE + " REAL, " + COLUMN_DEPARTURE_TIME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_ARRIVAL_TIME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DURATION + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_AVAILABLE_SEATS + " INTEGER )");


        ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
        insertValues.put(COLUMN_DESTINATION, "Cape Town");
        insertValues.put(COLUMN_PRICE, 500);
        insertValues.put(COLUMN_DEPARTURE_TIME, "1200");
        insertValues.put(COLUMN_ARRIVAL_TIME, "1400");
        insertValues.put(COLUMN_DURATION, "2");
        insertValues.put(COLUMN_AVAILABLE_SEATS, 10);
        MyDB.insert(FLIGHTS, null, insertValues);

        ContentValues insertValues2 = new ContentValues();
        insertValues2.put(COLUMN_DESTINATION, "Johannesburg");
        insertValues2.put(COLUMN_PRICE, 1000);
        insertValues2.put(COLUMN_DEPARTURE_TIME, "1400");
        insertValues2.put(COLUMN_ARRIVAL_TIME, "1600");
        insertValues2.put(COLUMN_DURATION, "2");
        insertValues2.put(COLUMN_AVAILABLE_SEATS, 22);
        MyDB.insert(FLIGHTS, null, insertValues2);


    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase MyDB, int i, int i1) {
        MyDB.execSQL("drop Table if exists users");
        MyDB.execSQL("drop Table if exists " + FLIGHTS);

        onCreate(MyDB);
    }

    public Boolean insertData(String username, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("username", username);
        contentValues.put("password", password);
        long result = MyDB.insert("users", null, contentValues);
        if(result==-1) return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Boolean checkusername(String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = MyDB.rawQuery("Select * from users where username = ?", new String[]{username});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public Boolean checkusernamepassword(String username, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase MyDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = MyDB.rawQuery("Select * from users where username = ? and password = ?", new String[] {username,password});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    public List<FlightsModel> getEveryone(){

        List<FlightsModel> returnList = new ArrayList<>();

        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + FLIGHTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String destination = cursor.getString(1);
                double price = cursor.getDouble(2);
                String departure = cursor.getString(3);
                String arrival = cursor.getString(4);
                String duration = cursor.getString(5);
                int space = cursor.getInt(6);

                FlightsModel newFlight = new FlightsModel(id, destination, price, departure, arrival, duration, space);
                returnList.add(newFlight);


            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else{

        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return returnList;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add the following method to the DBHelper class

:-

```
@SuppressLint("Range") // suppress Bug/issue with getColumnIndex
public FlightsModel getFlightById(int id) {
    FlightsModel rv;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Uses the query convenience method rather than raw query
    Cursor csr = db.query(FLIGHTS,null,COLUMN_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = new FlightsModel(
                csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DESTINATION)),
                csr.getDouble(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PRICE)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DEPARTURE_TIME)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ARRIVAL_TIME)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_DURATION)),
                csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_AVAILABLE_SEATS))
        );
    }  else {
        rv = new FlightsModel();
    }
    csr.close();
    // No need to close the database (inefficient to keep opening and clsoing db)
    return rv;
}
```

- note that `getWritableDatabase` has been used, it doesn't really matter which is used as `getReadableDatabase` will, unless the database can only be read, get a writeable database. i.e. `getReadableDatabase` will not protect against writes.
- it is better to use getColumnIndex than hard code column indexes. Thus irrespective of the position of the column the column will be found, thus  reducing potential maintenance issues.

2. Change the BookingActivity to retrieve the respective FlightsModel

:-

```
public class BookingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    TextView textView;
    DBHelper dbHelper; //<<<<< ADDED
    FlightsModel flightsModel; //<<<<< ADDED
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this); //<<<<< ADDED

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
        flightsModel = dbHelper.getFlightById(intValue); //<<<<< get the flightModel from the database
        if (flightsModel.id > 1) {
            // set the appropriate textviews
        } else {
            // do something here to indicate no FlightsModel found in database
        }
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(intValue)); 
    }
}
```